# Is it possible to switch application in app store to private(enterprise)?

Tags: ios, app-store, private

I have application which has to be available only in NY and it's already published in test flight. Can I switch it to enterprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "switch" they are two entirely different processes. You need to create a new [Enterprise account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/), create enterprise certs, re-build / sign the app. Then you need to find some way to distribute it to your users.

If you don't want it in the app store, you'll need to remove it if it is already there.

Please be aware that using an enterprise account is not a way to bypass the app store. Enterprise accounts are only to be used for "internal" apps. Its not meant to be distributed outside the control of a company, or its employeess